# Android - SurfaceView: To use or not to use a spritesheet?

Tags: android, sprite, surfaceview, out-of-memory

I'm currently trying to create a game for a tablet device for Android using a SurfaceView. I have sprites and what not, but I'm struggling if I should use a whole spritesheet (With every animation in it), or just seperate the sprites on image files.

For example, my spritesheet is named bear.png, which contains 16 images inside. I can animate them beautifully using Rect (Thanks to mybringback for this):

`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rectSrc, rectDest, null);`

But, I fear doing so would grow to larger than the heap size eventually.

However, there is another method. By seperating each image (bear1.png, bear2.png until bear16.png), I will also be able to create an animation with these sprites via:

`Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier("bear" + index, "drawable", "com.example.game"));`

then calling that to the canvas:

`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, bitmapX, bitmapY, null);`

Which also works fine for now. And of course, it greatly reduces my heap size since I'm only using 1 image at a time. But, because well.. Because, I'd be recalling Bitmap.decodeResource() at almost all times, I fear that when putting many animations together at one time, it may cause a significant lag.

So in short: 
- Spritesheets: Increased heap size (which may eventually lead to an OutOfMemory error), but better performance 
- Sprites on different image files: Decreased heap size, but may hinder performance 

I'm not entirely sure which approach to use. Would it actually be okay if I go with the second method (Sprites on different image files)?  Or would it be better with just spritesheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just answered my own question. It appears that rendering  `Bitmap.decodeResource()`  on every iteration lags the whole canvas, rather than rendering actual spritesheets and using `Rect`. Performance-wise, if experiencing too much lag on the canvas, there's no other way other than to shrink images using `inSampleSize` or using `GLSurfaceView`.